# How to display system menu on CDialog popup?

Tags: windows, mfc, cdialog, systemmenu

I have a CDialog based application.  In the Visual Studio resource editor the properties for my dialog show the style is set to "Popup" and the System Menu value is "True".  However when I run my application there is no system menu; how can I get a system menu to show?  Do I need to set an icon first with SetIcon()?

Here is the definition of my dialog from the resource file:

```
IDD_MAIN_DIALOG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 637, 371
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE
| WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it seems you need an icon to display the system menu.  I added an icon resource to my project and then called the following in my OnInitDialog() method:

```
SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(IDI_APP_ICON), TRUE);
```

Now my app has an icon and when I left click on it, it shows the system menu.